# How to impute daily rainfall missing data

Tags: missing-data, data-imputation

I have a data daily rainfall from 104 stations. The problem is what are the suitable packages to solve my missing value by using R.  Most of the program are suitable for multivariate data. Im prefer inverse distance weighting method. Or any other suggestion are most welcome.
my data is look like this
Time           MM
1/Jan/1990     2.0
2/Jan/1990     NA
3/Jan/1990     11.0
and so on

all stations have missing value less than 10%

Comment: Are  trying to calculate/interpolate the missing values spatially (e.g. how rain has fallen in the areas between the 104 stations?)  The reason I ask is because you mention inverse distance weighting...

Comment: Can you teach me how to solve by using R. Actually im trying to compare the result (smallest RMSE) between inverse distance weighting(IDW) and K-nearest neighbour (KNN) and also multiple imputation (MI)..or can i contact you personally..sorry if to many question

Comment: yes im trying calculate spatially :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to spatially interpolate (and IDW in particular), I would use the R package `gstat`  see here:  [gstat package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gstat/index.html) which also has some nice tutorials.

Here is a easy tutorial for you to read through (it uses precipitation and goes through a couple of different spatial interpolation algorithms) that should point you in the right direction [Interpolation in R](https://mgimond.github.io/Spatial/interpolation-in-r.html)

Comment: just remember to vote for the answer if it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

I have used MICE package in R for missing values imputation. You can take a reference from the link https://www.r-bloggers.com/imputing-missing-data-with-r-mice-package/.

Comment: Thank you so much.. will try it ..really appreciate your comment